# Mamp Pro, how fix this issue? InnnoDB

Tags: php, mysql, drupal-7, mamp-pro

I install Mamp pro but when I want to process the project, I have this error in mysql:

InnoDB:

> Error: Fetch of persistent statistics requested for table "atlasdb."
>   "Watchdog" but the required system tables mysql.innodb_table_stats and
>   mysql.innodb_index_stats are not present or have unexpected structure.
>   Using transient stats instead.

Comment: I have the same problem suddenly